# trying get the value in 2 selects dropdown doesn't work as expected

Tags: jquery, html

I have two selects with the same class and differents id. One of them is hidden, but when I'm trying get the value,  I only get the value of the first select what I selected. Help please.

HTML

```
        <input id="marcas" name="tipoSearch" type="radio" onclick="opcionSearch(this.id)"><span id="spanmarcas" class="spancat">por Marcas</span>
        <input id="categorias" name="tipoSearch" type="radio" onclick="opcionSearch(this.id)"><span id="spancategorias" class="spancat">por Categor&iacute;as</span>
        <select id="selmarcas" class="selbuscar" style="display:none;"></select>
        <select id="selcategorias" class="selbuscar" style="display:none;"></select>
        <input id="butBuscar" type="button" value="Buscar" disabled="disabled"/>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function opcionSearch(opcion){
    document.getElementById('butBuscar').disabled=false;
    if(opcion=='marcas'){
        $('input[name=tipoSearch]').show();
        $('.selbuscar').prop('disabled', true); 
        $('.selbuscar').hide();
        $('.spancat').show();
        $('#'+opcion).hide();
        $('#span'+opcion).hide();
        $('#sel'+opcion).show();
        $('#sel'+opcion).prop('disabled', false);            
    }
    else{
        $('input[name=tipoSearch]').show();
        $('.selbuscar').prop('disabled', true); 
        $('.selbuscar').hide();
        $('.spancat').show();
        $('#'+opcion).hide();
        $('#span'+opcion).hide();
        $('#sel'+opcion).show();
        $('#sel'+opcion).prop('disabled', false);
    }
}

$('#butBuscar').click(function(){

        var value = $('.selbuscar').val();
        alert(value)

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('#butBuscar').click(function () {
    $('.selbuscar').each(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        alert(value)
    });
});
```

You can loop through all the `selbuscar` drop-downs and then get the selected values of each.

**UPDATE**

For getting the value of the enabled drop down, you can do this:

```
$('#butBuscar').click(function () {
     var value = $('.selbuscar:enabled').val();
     alert(value);
});
```

Comment: I get the value of the two selects, but if I only want to get the value of the last  selected select. How can I get this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select[class^='selbuscar']").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    alert(value);
});
```